# HashMap gets wrong size

Tags: java, hashmap, set

I am trying to export some keys as byte[] from a HashSet to a HashMap and use the HashMap do store pairs of data. However, I am running into a problem, which is that the size om the set is larger than the size of the HashMap, for some reason. I would like to know what causes this as the HashMap is within a foreach which iterates from 0 to the size of the HashSet, namely 2^20. So, I am also expecting the size of the HashMap also to be 2^20.

So, what I am trying to store in the HashMap is two byte arrays. I am currently working with the meet-in-the-middle attack on 2DES. My encryption are properly implemented. In addition, my DES key generator is also properly implemented, so I am able to generate 2^20 keys (only 20 bits of the keys are effective). However, I when I try to put the keys in the HashMap the size is not the same as the HashSet, which doesn't make any sense.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, 20); i++) {
    possibleKeySet.add(generateDesKey());
}

for (byte[] key : possibleKeySet) {
    intermediateCipher.put((encrypt(key, plainText)).toString(), key);
}
```

Output:
Set size: `1048576`
Map size: `1048295`

PS: intermediateCipher is my HashMap.

Update:
I have tried to implement hashcode and equals, but i'm not sure how to implement hashcode.

```
class ByteArray {

    private byte[] key;

    ByteArray(byte[] key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    byte[] getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(obj);
      oos.writeObject(obj);
      oos.flush();
      byte [] data = bos.toByteArray();
      return key.equals(data);
}

    public int hashCode() {
        // what should I write here?
    }

}
```

Comment: You probably have a collision on keys. You can check it by checking the return value of `put` method. If no collision occurs it will return null.

Comment: But a set doesn't allow duplicates? so, that should not be any collision?

Comment: `(encrypt(key, plainText)` this will probably produce duplicates. You can check it by adding `if(putReturn != null) sysout(putReturn)`

Comment: I tried with   if (intermediateCipher.get(key) != null) {System.out.println("NULL");} but it did never print "NULL"

Comment: You have to check return value of `intermediateCipher.put((encrypt(key, plainText)).toString(), key);`

Comment: Are you sure that a duplicate key isn't possible?

Comment: He is using `byte[]` as a key ... so duplicates are possible.

Answer (score 3):

The probability of a hash collision is (as can be [seen here](https://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/)):

[image: graph]

The average number of collisions for a set of size `n` given `k` inputs is:

[image: N(n,k)~=k(k-1)/(2n)]

Given an `n` of `2^32` and a `k` of `2^20`, the average collision is

```
(2^20) * (2^20 - 1) / (2 * 2^32)
~= 2^40/2^33
~= 2^7
~= 128
```

The number of collisions you saw was `1048576 - 1048295 = 281`. Given this info I assume that the actual entropy of the value returned by `encrypt(key, plainText)` is roughly ~31 bits (rather than 32).

---

To get the desired amount of keys, you may want to just keep generating values until you reach the desired size. This may make the method take a long time to complete:

```
while (intermediateCipher.size() < Math.pow(2,20)) {
    byte[] key = generateDesKey();
    intermediateCipher.put((encrypt(key, plainText)).toString(), key);
}
```

---

Comment: Very interesting, but how do I avoid the collision?

Comment: Even with hash collision `HashSet` and `HashMap` is using equals for checking collision (So first hashCode bucket, then a list with equals checking). In my answer, I provide a full solution to the problem.

Comment: @user8231110 I added a simple way to get the desired size!

Comment: but possibleKeySet.add(generateDesKey()); is a HashSet, so I cannot store it in a byte[]

Comment: @user8231110 Just call  `intermediateCipher.values()` to get them. After the while loop you could even do: `possibleKeySet.addAll(intermediateCipher.values())`

Comment: but intermediateCipher does not have any values prior to adding the keys in the HashSet

Comment: "Very interesting, but how do I avoid the collision?"  - You can't.  You don't.  You detect the collision ... and generate another key to replace it.  @flakes - the collisions are in `possibleKeySet`!

Comment: @user8231110 why do you need them in the `HashSet` first? You can skip creating the `possibleKeySet` altogether. The `intermediateCipher` will contain both the set of hashes produced by `encrypt(key, plainText)` and the original `byte[]` key values.

Comment: So, I can just have a while loop, which iterates until the size of intermediateCipher is 2^20. Within the loop I call       intermediateCipher.put((encrypt(generateDesKey(), plainText)).toString(), generateDesKey());

Comment: @user8231110 that's close, but not quite. I assume `generateDesKey()` produces a different value every call. If you call it twice you will get two different keys. Take a look at the last section of my answer.

Comment: You are right, it generates two different keys. By looking at your last section: while (intermediateCipher.size() < Math.pow(2, 20)) {
   byte[] key = generateDesKey();
      intermediateCipher.put((encrypt(key, plainText)).toString(), key);
  }

Comment: @user8231110 looks good to me. Next up you should write some unit tests to fully verify that it works!

Answer (score 1):

If your `Set` and `HashMap` have a different size it will probably be a collision on keys.
It looks like your function `encrypt(key, plainText)` return duplicates.

Try with:

```
for (byte[] key : possibleKeySet) {
    Object oldValue = intermediateCipher.put((encrypt(key, plainText)).toString(), key);
    if(oldValue != null) {
        System.out.println("Duplicated!");
    }
}
```

It will probably produce some errors.

Take a note also, that `generateDesKey()` can also produce the same values even if they are stored in `Set` as two arrays in Java are only equal if they are the same object.

What you can do? Create a custom object:

```
class ByteArray {

    private byte[] key;

    ByteArray(byte[] key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    byte[] getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //implement your equals logic using array members equality
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        //implement your hashCode logic using array members equality
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I do have some duplicates.  How do I then make sure that the keys in the Set are unique. Then using it makes no sense, if the values in the Set aren't unique

Comment: You can use a new custom object which will store your array as a field and then override hashCode and equals to check what is INSIDE array.

Comment: They are unique only by design of equals of an array. Not unique in by author algorithm design - the array is not fit here to be used as part of a set.

Comment: I think the symptoms mean that your `generateDesKey` is generating non-unique keys ... as well.

Comment: For generating a key, I'm using SecureRandom()

Comment: What is your question now? I provide a solution and answer why your set size is different than HashSet size. If you have another question - in the example with helping create better function it should be a new separate question.

Comment: I had tried to implement the equal and hashcode but I'm not sure how to implement the hashcode. I have given it a try and hope you can help me.

Comment: Use for that `Arrays.hashCode` and `Arrays.equals`

Answer (score 0):

The set itself is being implemented that way that every item inside must be unique - **it does not allow duplicates**. That means that when you are putting to set two equal objects in result in set there will be only one.

Probably your `generateDesKey()` method is returning not unique values for all of `2^20` values and in the result set the items count is less than `2^20`

Basically you can check the `possibleKeySet` size before copying values to the `HashMap` like

```
System.out.println(possibleKeySet.size());
```

or just by using debugger

Comment: I did that and the size is 1048576 (2^20)

Comment: Actually, not weird.  Bytearrays (arrays in general) can't be used as keys in a HashSet or HashMap.  Because of the semantics of `equals`.  See ByeBye's answer.

Comment: But he is using a String as the key